# How can I remove outer brackets without expanding content?

Tags: macros, expansion, expl3, pgfkeys

I'm trying to use `pgfkeys` to collect information that will be passed to a `clist`.  But, I'm not able to get this to work correctly.  It seems that I'm getting brackets around the list and is prevent `\clist_map_inline:Nn` from parsing its argument as desired.

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_new:N \l_ae_itemize_element_clist
\cs_new:Npn \_ae_itemize:n #1 
  {
    \clist_set:Nn \l_ae_itemize_element_clist {#1}
    \begin{itemize}
      \clist_map_inline:Nn \l_ae_itemize_element_clist { \item ##1 }
    \end{itemize}
  }
\NewDocumentCommand{\aeItemizeElements}{m}
  { \_ae_itemize:n {#1} }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\pgfkeys
  {
    /ae/list example/.cd,
    title/.initial =,
    content/.initial = {},
  }

\def\aeSet#1{\pgfkeys{/ae/list example/.cd,#1}}
\def\aeGet#1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/ae/list example/#1}}

\NewDocumentCommand{\aeItemizeA}{ m }
  {\aeSet{#1}%%'
   \noindent\textbf{\aeGet{title}}%%'
   \aeItemizeElements{\aeGet{content}}
  }

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\aeItemizeA{title=Works as expected,content=\textbf{only one item}}

\aeItemizeA{title=Not iterating over content,content={first item, second item}}

\end{document}
```

To get the second list to be formatted correctly, I could do something like

```
\clist_set:Nx \l_ae_itemize_element_clist {#1}
```

But that crashes on the first list because it's expanding the content.

Is there a way to automatically strip away outer brackets, if they're there, while not expanding the content, or doing nothing if there are no outer brackets?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you've chosen `pgfkeys` over `l3keys`?

Comment: @cgnieder Mostly because I'm trying to learn how to use `pgfkeys`.  But also, `pgfkeys` seems to have a simpler syntax for some things such as for saving and storing values.

Comment: I don’t know much about `expl3` (and without taking a closer look at your example) but removing `{}` should be easy doable with a combination of `\@ifnextchar\bgroup` and `\@firstofone`.

Comment: It isn't really a matter of having `{}` around the list, it just isn't a list at all until you execute the pgf keys instructions, the macro is: `> \l_ae_itemize_element_clist=macro:
->\aeGet {content}.`

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel If you could write that up as an answer, I would accept. Changing `content/.initial` to `content/.code = {\@ifnextchar\bgroup{\expandafter\@ae@remove@bracket\@firstofone}{\@ae@remove@bracket{#1}}}` and defining `\def\@ae@remove@bracket#1{\def\mycontent{#1}}` did the trick.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Considering your comment, I've tried several approaches in the `expl3` code to extract the content of `\aeGet{content}` before moving on to the `clist`, but I seem to only be able to get the name of the underlying macro, or other errors.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_new:N \l_ae_itemize_element_clist
\cs_new:Npn \_ae_itemize:n #1 
  {
    \clist_set:No \l_ae_itemize_element_clist {\romannumeral`\^^@#1}
    \begin{itemize}
      \clist_map_inline:Nn \l_ae_itemize_element_clist { \item ##1 }
    \end{itemize}
  }
\NewDocumentCommand{\aeItemizeElements}{m}
  { \_ae_itemize:n {#1} }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\pgfkeys
  {
    /ae/list example/.cd,
    title/.initial =,
    content/.initial = {},
  }

\def\aeSet#1{\pgfkeys{/ae/list example/.cd,#1}}
\def\aeGet#1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/ae/list example/#1}}

\NewDocumentCommand{\aeItemizeA}{ m }
  {\aeSet{#1}%%'
   \noindent\textbf{\aeGet{title}}%%'
   \aeItemizeElements{\aeGet{content}}
  }

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\aeItemizeA{title=Works as expected,content=\textbf{only one item}}

\aeItemizeA{title=Not iterating over content,content={first item, second item}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What's the ``\clist_set:No \l_ae_itemize_element_clist {\romannumeral`\^^@#1}`` business about? Looks like an f-type expansion to me

Comment: I know `\romannumeral`, but how is that that helps here?  I'm intrigued and quite mystified by this *magic*.

Comment: @JosephWright the whole point of l3 expansion control is not to have to do that, but habits die hard:-)

Comment: @JosephWright Thank you for that comment.  By defining a variant, `\clist_set:Nf`, I was able to get the effect desired without having to detect braces.

Comment: @A.Ellett See http://www.texdev.net/2011/07/05/expansion-using-romannumeral/ for how the magic works

Comment: @A.Ellett note I get a rap on the knuckles from Joseph for the somewhat impure approach:-) The interesting feature of `\romannumeral` is that it expands all tokens until it gets an unexpandable token then stops (unlike edef which would start expanding the next token) the `\^^@ is 0 so the eventual romannumeral that results is 0 which is the empty string but after that is the initial expansion of the input up to the first non expandable token.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Got it.

Comment: @JosephWright Thank you for the link.  Quite useful.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a `pgfkeys`-only approach (and a little bit `pgffor` for the `.list` handler).

The `\romannumeral` trick is used to get the content of the `content` key without expanding it (we can’t `edef` it because of possible unexpandable stuff (like `\textbf`)). This is only used to test the `content` key for contents. It is not needed otherwise.

A `\rumannumeral`-less version is given below with two expansions (including nine `\expandafter`s).

The `\aeGet{content}` needs to be expanded four times so that we get to its content.

1. `\pgfkeysvalueof{/ae/list example/content}`
2. `\csname pgfk@/ae/list example/content\endcsname`
3. `\pgfk@/ae/list example/content`
4. `<content>`

Of course you can shorten this by giving the raw `\csname` version (similar to the `\romannumeral`-less version of `\def\aeTemp`).

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys,pgffor}
\def\aeSet{\pgfqkeys{/ae/list example}}
\def\aeGet#1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/ae/list example/#1}}
\aeSet{
  title/.initial=,
  content/.initial=,
  itemize/.code={\item #1}%
}
\newcommand{\aeItemizeA}[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \aeSet{#1}
    \noindent\textbf{\aeGet{title}}%
    \expandafter\def\expandafter\aeTemp\expandafter{\romannumeral-`0\aeGet{content}}%
    % or:
%     \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\def
%     \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\aeTemp
%     \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\csname pgfk@/ae/list example/content\endcsname}%
    \itemize
      \ifx\aeTemp\empty
        \item \itshape empty!
      \else
        \aeSet{itemize/.list/.expand twice/.expand twice=\aeGet{content}}
      \fi
    \enditemize
  \endgroup
}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\aeItemizeA{title=No entry given!}

\aeItemizeA{title=Works as expected,content=\textbf{only one item}}

\aeItemizeA{title=Not iterating over content,content={first item, second item}}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 5):

It's easier without `pgfkeys`, in my opinion.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_new:N \l_ae_itemize_element_clist
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \clist_map_inline:nn { f }
\cs_new:Npn \_ae_itemize:n #1 
 {
  \begin{itemize}
    \clist_map_inline:fn {#1} { \item ##1 }
  \end{itemize}
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\aeItemizeElements}{m}
 { \_ae_itemize:n {#1} }

\keys_define:nn { ae/list }
 {
  title   .tl_set:N  = \l_ae_list_title_tl,
  title   .initial:n = {},
  content .tl_set:N  = \l_ae_list_content_tl,
  content .initial:n = {},
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\aeSet}{m}
 {
  \keys_set:nn { ae/list } { #1 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\aeItemizeA}{ m }
 {
  \group_begin:
  \aeSet{#1}
  \noindent\textbf{\l_ae_list_title_tl}
  \aeItemizeElements{\l_ae_list_content_tl}
  \group_end:
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\aeItemizeA{title=Works as expected,content=\textbf{only one item}}

\aeItemizeA{title=Iterating over content,content={first item, second item}}

\newcommand{\test}{Item A, Item B}

\aeItemizeA{title=This has a control sequence for content, content=\test}

\end{document}
```

[image]